# How to use Ruby Module comparison

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use the module comparison functions of [Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3C). Consider the code:

```rb
module Mod
  module Mod2
  end
end

module ModExtend
  extend Mod
end

puts (Mod<Mod::Mod2).nil?    # Prints "true"
puts (Mod<ModExtend).nil?    # Prints "true"
```

I would expect `Mod<Mod::Mod2` to return `false` rather than `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ruby documentation of [Module#<](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-3C)

> Returns true if mod is a subclass of other. Returns nil if there’s no
>   relationship between the two. (Think of the relationship in terms of
>   the class definition: “class A<B” implies “A<B”).

Now we observe the modules ancestors

```
Mod.ancestors       # [Mod]
Mod::Mod2.ancestors # [Mod::Mod2]
ModExtend.ancestors # [ModExtend]
```

As you can see, there is no ancestor relation between them.

However a module defined with:

```
module Mod3
  include Mod
end
```

Gives:

```
Mod3 < Mod     # true
Mod3.ancestors # [Mod3, Mod]
```

According to the documentation `false` is never returned by `Module#<`. However, `nil` is a falsy value (it acts like `false` in boolean expressions: `!nil #-> true`).

Comment: Okay, so the missing piece was that I needed to include the parent module to be considered "subclasses". Thanks!